# How to use lightning.force.com Platform

Tags: lightning

I'm using salesforce login of URL : https://Mydomain_name.lightning.force.com

This is my first time to use this Lightning platform. 
I'm not seen anywhere development options(Setup) in this org.

How can i start my development in this. means from where i can create objects, workoflows, Vf pages, classes and triggers.

Please Guide me;

I'm just visible like this;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the below trailhead Module to kick start the Lightning basics and learn all the different module that is needed.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/module/lex_migration_introduction